# Does the derivative operator have an adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, adjoint-operators

> Determine whether the linear operator $T(f) = f'$ (taking the derivative) has an adjoint or not.

Consider the inner product $\left<f,g\right> = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t)\ dt $ defined on the vector space $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of all real polynomials and let $T(f) = f'$.
Now we need to decide whether $T$ has a adjoint or not

*It can be checked that T is neither normal or self-adjoint, but I struggle in determining whether there is an adjoint or not. I also consider creating some examples but it is impossible to write out an orthonormal basis and plug in the formula since we're dealing with an infinite vector space...*

Comment: Look at slides 14+ in [this presentation](https://mathcourses.nfshost.com/archived-courses/mat-531-2015-spring/lectures/21a-the-adjoint-of-a-linear-operator.pdf)

Comment: @gt6989b Since $T$ is densely defined, should it not have an adjoint? It would seem to me that the way to resolve the issue raised in the slides is to define the adjoint on a proper subset $\mathbb{R}[x]$. However, I could certainly be mistaken.

Comment: Using by-parts integration, $T^\ast = \delta(t-1)-\delta(t)-\frac{d}{dt}$ (depending on how you define dirac with endpoints, don't remember). Thus, $T^\ast g$ is in general a distribution, not a function. Unless you restrict to functions $f$ with $f(0)=f(1)$, then $T^\ast=-\frac{d}{dt}$ simply.

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I have reworked the proof.

I came up with a rather simple method: consider $f = 1$ (or any constant) and $g=x^2$ we have

$$\langle T(f), x^2 \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}f'(t)x^2 dt = 0 = \langle f, T^*(x^2) \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}1 * T^*(x^2) dt  $$

Now, observe that there exists F(x) where $ \frac{dF(t)}{dt} = T^*(x^2) $. $F(1)-F(0) = 0$.

Consider $\frac{dF(t^2)}{dt} = \frac{dF(t^2)}{dt^2} = T^*(x^4) * 2t$.

Now, $\langle T(x), x^4 \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}x^4dt = \frac{1}{5} $

But $\langle x, T^*(x^4) \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}t * T^*(x^4) dt  = F(1)-F(0)  =0$

This is a contradiction.

Comment: Does $\int_0^1(x-\tfrac{1}{2})dx=0$ imply $x-\tfrac{1}{2}\equiv0$ identically?

Comment: how are you concluding that $\int_0^1f'(t)g(t)dt=0$ no matter what $f$ or $g$ is??

Comment: @Dinoman As others have pointed out, your proof has problems. :(

Comment: Could integration by part be used, then a condition on the boundary may be set.

Comment: @Cretin2 that is what the proof in the slides shows, posted in the comment section underneath the question by  gt6989b

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier I have reworked the proof again.